# Using pygame Joystick in pyglet

Tags: python, pygame, pyglet, joystick, gamepad

I'm trying to write a simple game with pyglet but use pygame for gamepad input. The following code successfully prints axis values to the command line, but aside from importing pyglet, doesn't actually show a pyglet window:

```
import pygame
import math
import sys
import pyglet

pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()    
js = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
js.init()

while True:
    pygame.event.get()
    jx = js.get_axis(0)    
    print('axis 0: ' + str(jx))
```

I'm not sure what role pygame.event.get() plays, but without it, the returned axis value is always just zero.

So now when I try to use the Joystick in my pyglet events, I always just get zero as the value (even if I hold the stick in position and move the window around to trigger draw events):

```
import pygame
import math
import sys
import pyglet

pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()    
js = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
js.init()

window = pyglet.window.Window()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    jx = js.get_axis(0)    
    print('axis 0: ' + str(jx))
    window.clear()

pyglet.app.run()
```

If I toss a pygame.event.get() into on_draw(), I get a blank white window which I can't drag with no console output (until I hit esc, closing the window and exiting, at which point several axis values get printed, all zero). Is event.get() stuck blocked?

So despite what is suggested at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/psychopy-users/GWNE4RvGbRE/TNRKM1L2PBwJ, using pygame Joystick seems to involve more than just importing it and initializing.

Perhaps if I use pygame's event handling it would work, but that might have its own problems when drawing with pyglet from a pygame even handler.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'll just side-step this issue by using Pyglet 1.21alpha, which includes joystick support.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem was that you didn't put it in a while loop. That way it doesn't just print once, so for example your function (which I haven't tested) but should work, looks something like this.

```
def on_draw():
 while True:
  jx = js.get_axis(0)
  print('axis 0: '+ str(jx))
  window.clear()
```